# MVC Edit action does not save related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a collection related to an class but I cannot save them to a database. Other members are saved successfully but collection not.

```
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ProductTypeId,Name,IsActive")] ProductType productType, string[] chkAttributeCategory)
    {

        productType.AttributeCategories.Clear();
        if (chkAttributeCategory != null)
        {
            foreach (string attributeCategory in chkAttributeCategory)
            {
                productType.AttributeCategories.Add(db.AttributeCategory.Find(int.Parse(attributeCategory)));
            }
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(productType).State = EntityState.Modified;                                
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(productType);
    }
```

I have a checkbox list on my view whick represents a list of child objects. I've checked the *productType* object before save changes line in debuger and it contains everything he needs, but associated AttributeCategories are not saved in the database.

Somebody has idea ?

Comment: `productType` is not a proxy, the change tracker will not work for disconnected object, you need to get the `productType` first from db or manually manage the relationship. Is it one to many or many to many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating an entity from a disconnected object, the change tracker will not work, changes to non scalar properties will not work.

If you do like this, it should work.

```
var productTypeDb = db.Set<ProductType>()
    .Include(pt => pt.AttributeCategories)
    .FirstOrDefault(pt => pt.ProductTypeId == productType.ProductTypeId)
productTypeDb.AttributeCategories.Clear();
if (chkAttributeCategory != null)
{
    foreach (string attributeCategory in chkAttributeCategory)
    {
        productTypeDb.AttributeCategories.Add(db.AttributeCategory
            .Find(int.Parse(attributeCategory)));
    }
}

productTypeDb.Name = productType.Name;
productTypeDb.IsActive = productType.IsActive;
// other properties

db.SaveChanges();
```

There is another way to manage the state manually to be able to work with disconnected object, but if that's not mandatory, you can do like above code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't have a list or an array in a model that's not a view model, I think you need to have a separate model with each product type linked to attributes:

```
//model1
public class ProductTypeCategory{
public int ProductTypeID {get; set;}
public int CategoryID {get; set;}
}
//model2
public class Category{
public int ID {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

now you can get the attributes this way:

```
List<Category> attributes = (from p in db.ProductTypeCategories from c in db.Categories where p.ProductTypeID == productTypeID && p.CategoryID == c.ID select c).toList();
```

just input the id of the product type in the above LINQ call an you'll get its categories